# CORS Request Aborted in Firefox, not in Chrome or IE

Tags: ajax, apache, cors

I am making a cross-domain ajax request with jQuery.  This request works fine in Chrome, and even IE.  But in Firefox, the preflight OPTIONS is always aborted by Firefox.  The destination server of this request is Apache, and has CORS enabled in the httpd-vhosts.conf

Even more frustrating is that the first request made by Firefox fails.  Subsequent refreshes with F5 - the ajax call **sometimes** completes.  In Firebug - I don't see the preflight OPTIONS request made.  I've spent far too long trying to solve this - any help greatly appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
    ServerName cyrsggisprd01.sgaas.gi-mss.com
    SSLVerifyClient none
    WSGIScriptAlias /svm_server D:\Apache24\htdocs\svm_server\adapter.wsgi
    <Directory D:\Apache24\htdocs\svm_server>
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
        Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, session"

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
        RewriteRule .* / [R=200,L]

        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile D:\Apache24\ssl\server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile D:\Apache24\ssl\server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need to supply more information. Such as what kind of request you are making.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old question, but I had a very similar issue to this with a different setup involving IIS instead of Apache, but I managed to figure it out. The core issue was CORS, SSL, and untrusted certificates.

In my case, the CORS client (which is a SPA served from its own URL) and server had untrusted certificates, but an exception was set up for the client in Firefox but not the server. This meant Firefox loaded the SPA successfully, but any CORS requests the SPA made to the server were simply aborted during the pre-flight phase with no further explanation. I believe (but I have not confirmed) Edge does a similar thing with the following error: "Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied".

So, basically, double check to see your servers have valid certificates, and add any exceptions you need to your browsers. All I had to do in Firefox was to manually visit the server URL and add an exception, and that made the problem go away. This simple step is something that is very easy to overlook (especially when setting up a new development environment), and it can be very frustrating to debug as the generated error messages are misleading.